# Magento administration - error when trying to access categories (catalog - categories)

Tags: php, magento

I get this error when trying to enter catalog/categories, I have tried everything possible with no result, my version of Magento is 1.7:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Source model "legenda/system_config_source_attribute_columns" not found for attribute "sw_lg_cat_design"

Trace:
#0 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "l...')
#1 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/tricka/app/code/local/GoMage/Navigation/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(183): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): GoMage_Navigation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#5 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#6 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#8 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#9 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#10 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#11 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#13 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#14 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#15 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#17 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#20 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#21 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#22 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#23 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#24 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#25 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /home/tricka/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /home/tricka/app/Mage.php(698): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /home/tricka/index.php(87): Mage::run('tricka_cz', 'website')
#29 {main}
```

Answer (score -1):

- go via cPanel
- find table mage_eav_attribute
- erase tables that starts with sw_

You have most certainly installed a theme that uploads attribute to database.